# What does "tightening" mean in the phrase "tightening election polls"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The team, led by Vincent Chalgneau, the bank’s head of fixed-income strategy, and Guy Stear, its head of emerging markets, concluded that a Trump victory would likely hurt emerging-market currencies as investors brace for more protectionist trade policies in the U.S. Indeed, many emerging-market currencies are already responding to **tightening election polls**, it appears. The correlation can be seen in the graph below:

source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/heres-how-the-us-election-might-impact-the-currency-market-2016-09-09

What does "tightening" mean in the phrase "tightening election polls"?

Comment: The gap is becoming smaller.  The vertical legend on the left side has a minus sign, thus, the plotted value is a difference (support for candidate A minus the support for candidate B set against the plotted values of currency fluctuation).

Comment: Definition #11 in the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary definition of tight](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tight_1?q=tight) may be helpful. If you look over the other definitions, you can see that tight/tighten has a quite a few different meanings depending on what you're talking about. Tight also is used as [slang to describe something that is really great](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32826/80039).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that the difference/distance between the competitors/contenders is narrowing down, getting smaller.